# Scapy sniffing the same packet that I just sent

Tags: scapy, packet-sniffers

I have an issue where if I send a packet and then sniff for a response to that sent packet, my s.sniff() function returns the packet that I just sent!

ex:

```
def sendOneFast(pkt):
    """
        Function: sendOneFast
        Purpose: Opens a layer 2 socket on interface, sends a packet on that socket.

        pkt -> Scapy packet to be sent
    """
    s = conf.L2socket(iface='Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM #2')
    s.send(pkt)
    l = s.sniff(iface = 'Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM #2', timeout = 0.03)
    return l
```

When i call this function for a packet, 'l' will be the packet that I sent! Note: this works correctly when I run the same code in Linux, but exhibits this behavior in Windows 7/10.

I have Python 2.7.X installed with the latest Scapy. What could be the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that both behaviors are "normal" (the root cause of the difference probably lies in Scapy's architecture-dependent internals), but you cannot assume that you will or won't see your own packet in that case (it could be called an undefined behavior).

Out of curiosity, which version exactly are you using? The latest == the current development, the latest stable release (2.4.0) or the current version packaged somewhere?

By the way, I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but are you aware there exists `sr()`, `srp()` (and `sr1()`, `srp1()`) if you want to catch answers to your packets?